# Sphinx search in android

Tags: android, sphinx

Is it possible to create Sphinx Search in Android?
Do not confuse with PocketSphinx. Sphinx Search - http://sphinxsearch.com/.

If it is not possible, what is the alternative?

Answer (score 0):

In theory it should be possible. An Android device is just a linux device - as long as sphinx could be compiled for the ARM based processor.

But installing a binary would almost certainly require root access to the device, and so would be outside the realm of bundling sphinx within a app the user could download from the Market.

Maybe something like compass[ http://compass-project.org/ ] would allow you to embed full-text search.

Another option may simply to use a hosted solution http://www.houndsleuth.com/